Is the mean of the Bayesian regression posterior a probability distribution itself?
I know that to find the mean and covariance matrix of the posterior distribution of the regression coefficients, we have to equate the exponents of the product of the likelihood and the prior and the posterior and solve w.r.t β:
$\begin{equation*}\exp \left( -\frac{1}{2\sigma^2} (\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{X}\beta)^T (\mathbf{y} - \mathbf{X}\beta) \right) \cdot \exp \left( -\frac{1}{2} \beta^T \Sigma_\beta^{-1} \beta \right) = \exp \left( -\frac{1}{2} (\beta - \hat{\beta})^T \Sigma_{\beta \mid \mathbf{y}}^{-1} (\beta - \hat{\beta}) \right)\end{equation*}$
Which yields
\begin{equation*}\hat{\beta} = (\Sigma_\beta^{-1} + \frac{1}{\sigma^2} \mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{X})^{-1} \frac{1}{\sigma^2} \mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{y}\end{equation*}\begin{equation*}
\Sigma_{\beta \mid \mathbf{y}} = (\Sigma_\beta^{-1} + \frac{1}{\sigma^2} \mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{X})^{-1}\end{equation*}
Where $\begin{align*}\hat{\beta}\end{align*}$ is the mean and $\begin{align*}\Sigma_{\beta \mid \mathbf{y}}\end{align*}$ is the covariance matrix of the posterior distribution of $\begin{align*}{\beta}\end{align*}$. However, the expression for $\begin{align*}\hat{\beta}\end{align*}$ still contains $\mathbf{y}$ which is normally distributed: $\mathbf{y} \sim \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{X} \beta, \sigma^2 \mathbf{I})$, so it should follow that the mean of the posterior is itself a Gaussian with a mean of $
\mathbb{E}[\hat{\beta}] = (\Sigma_\beta^{-1} + \frac{1}{\sigma^2} \mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{X})^{-1} \frac{1}{\sigma^2} \mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{X} \beta$ ?
If so what is the essence of $\begin{align*}{\beta}\end{align*}$? Is it just a vector of scalars or is it a distribution as well?

Preliminary: A real number is not a distribution. A random variable is not a distribution.

Main: A posteriori, $\hat\beta$ is the mean of the posterior distribution on $\beta$, hence a fixed real number for the observed realization of the random variable $\mathbf y$. Marginally, that is, when accounting for all possible realizations of $\mathbf y$ beyond the observed one, it is indeed a Normal/Gaussian variate. Accounting for the prior distribution on $\beta$,  $\hat\beta$ has a prior predictive distribution that is also Normal/Gaussian.
